# Why do I get a "No matching distribution found" error when installing a package I just uploaded to pypi?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, setup.py, python-packaging

I am trying to upload my package to PyPi. It uploads successfully every time but when I try to install it, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Google-Ads-Transparency-Scraper==1.4 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Google-Ads-Transparency-Scraper==1.4
```

The following is the directory structure I have

> - GoogleAds
>
>   - GoogleAdsTransparency
>
>     - __init __.py
>     - main.py
>     - regions.py
>   - setup.py
>   - setup.cfg
>   - license.txt
>   - README.md

The setup.py has the following content

```
"""Install packages as defined in this file into the Python environment."""
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="Google Ads Transparency Scraper",
    author="Farhan Ahmed",
    author_email="jattfarhan10@gmail.com",
    url="https://github.com/faniAhmed/GoogleAdsTransparencyScraper",
    description="A scraper for getting Ads from Google Transparency",
    version="1.4",
    packages=find_packages(),
    download_url= 'https://github.com/faniAhmed/GoogleAdsTransparencyScraper/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.tar.gz',
    keywords= ['Google', 'Transparency', 'Scraper', 'API', 'Google Ads', 'Ads', 'Google Transparency', 'Google Transparency Scraper', 'Google Ads Scrapre'],
    license='Securely Incorporation',
    install_requires=[
        "setuptools>=45.0",
        "beautifulsoup4>=4.12.2",
        "Requests>=2.31.0",
        "lxml>=4.6.3",
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
        "Environment :: Console",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "License :: Free for non-commercial use",
        "Natural Language :: Urdu",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
    ],
    platforms=["any"],
)
```

The setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
description-file = README.md
```

The **init**.py has the following content

```
from GoogleAdsTransparency.main import GoogleAds
from GoogleAdsTransparency.main import show_regions_list
```

I run the following commands to upload the package

```
python setup.py sdist
twine upload dist/*
```

The link to the package is
https://pypi.org/project/Google-Ads-Transparency-Scraper/

Comment: I have noted that you have 4 names for this package: (1) Google-Ads-Transparency-Scraper, (2) GoogleAdsTransparencyScraper, (3) GoogleAdsTransparency and (4) GoogleTrendsScraper. Your gitHub repository doesn't match what you uploaded to PyPI. You need to make sure that you can clone your package from GitHub before you push it to PyPi. You should also push to test PyPi to ensure that you can install from there before pushing to the main PyPi.

Comment: You mean tthe directory structure of github and PyPi is not same?

Comment: Should I have same name of the class, folder name and the name I provided in setup.py and the Github repo?

Comment: It's fine to have different names. The convention is to have the same name for all of those, but it is only a convention.

Comment: I really do not know what is going on. The packaging and its metadata (although unconventional) seems correct to me. But somehow _pip_ does not want to install it. When running with verbose output `pip install -vvv Google-Ads-Transparency-Scraper==1.4` I can see this kind of message: "_Skipping link: Missing project version for Google-Ads-Transparency-Scraper: https://..._", which is quite surprising to me. Maybe it is worth reporting the issue on _pip_ ticket tracker: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues

Comment: @farhanjatt If I were you, I would try to change the name of the project to replace the empty spaces ` ` with dashes `-`, so in `setup.py` we would have: `name="Google-Ads-Transparency-Scraper"`. Then update version number and upload again. Note that you could try on "Test PyPI" first, instead of the real PyPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be your problem, The file uploaded contains spaces where as when you see the second image, it should not contain spaces
[image]
[image]

By examining that, I come to the conclusion as to what is wrong. Do you have spaces inside your setup.py? If so, remove them, also the github page for your project is incomplete, it does not contain setup.py, so I can't diagnose any further. Please, if possible, give out the complete source code for such highly specific problems.

To look at the downloads available for a package:
[image]

So, i dug a little deeper, and found out this:

[image]

Your name contains spaces and your download_url is outdated.
After digging deeper by looking at verbose logs of pip:

[image]

I find that it is able to find the download link for the packages, but the issue is that, it is unable to find the project version from the link.

Comment: You can browse the contents of all distribution packages here: https://inspector.pypi.io/project/google-ads-transparency-scraper/ -- This is more reliable than the source code repository as it is exactly what is on PyPI, and also it is all online so you do not have to download anything (potentially harmful).

Comment: yep, i downloaded the tar archive

Comment: I am out here for the bounty really, I am still looking into it

Comment: OMFG, this is so confusing, Imma go and get deep into pip's source code for finding this issue.

Comment: After evaluating source code for pip, I have come to the conclusion that the issue lies within your package name containing spaces, I suggest you to try uploading the package without spaces in setup.py name field.

Comment: also, try using the version in format "1.5.0" just in case

Comment: ok, I will update you after doing the changes you said

Comment: I will award the bounty after an hour (limit from stackoverflow)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254330/discussion-between-farhan-jatt-and-amaank).